# "Target container is not a DOM element." When Running Webpack server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have recently switched from using 'npm start' script that comes with create-react-app to Weback's 'npm run build' and then running the server. After slowly getting all the dependencies working I got my bundle to complete building. However, when I use 'npm start' the server starts and *nothing shows up on my website*.

I tried inputting `<div id="root">` into my .html file in my "public" directory, but it didn't work. I then found out Webpack created a second for me? Either way placing a `<div>` or even a `<script>` in either one doesn't work.
I have updated all of my dependencies for react so that the ReactDOM could render peacefully. my React code worked perfectly before I switched to webpack so I'm sure it's not a problem with my index.js and whatever it imports.

I'm convinced it's a problem in webpack, but I've tried plenty of different presets in webpack.config.js and can't seem to find any that works (I have forgotten the ones I've tried so I will take any suggestions).

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',

    output: {
        filename: './main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist')
    },

    plugins: [new webpack.ProgressPlugin(), new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^pg-native$/)], 

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
                loader: 'babel-loader',

                options: {
                    plugins: [
                        'syntax-dynamic-import'
                    ],

                    presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/preset-react',
                            {
                                'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
                            }
                        ]
                }
            },

            {
                test:/\.(s*)css$/,
                use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }, 
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
            }
        ]
    },

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    priority: -10,
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
                }
            },

            chunks: 'async',
            minChunks: 1,
            minSize: 30000,
            name: true
        }
    },

    node: {
        fs: 'empty'
      }
    ,

    devServer: {
        open: true
    }
};
```

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App.js';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
let state = {};

window.setState = (changes) => {
    state = Object.assign({}, state, changes);

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App {...state}/>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}
/* eslint no-restricted-globals: 0*/
let initialState = {
    name: 'Name Test',
    location: location.pathname.replace(/^\/?|\/$/g, "")
};

window.setState(initialState);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

```
<!-- .HTML created by Webpack -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<!-- .HTML created by create-react-app (before webpack)-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Skedge</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I go into the web console this shows up as an error -

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Target container is not a DOM element.
>      at invariant (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/reactdom.development.js?:55:15)
>      at Object.render (webpack:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/reactdom.development.js?:21151:36)
>      at eval (webpack:///./src/index.js?:35:50)
>      at Module../src/index.js (http://localhost:8080/main.js:3970:1)
>      at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8080/main.js:20:30)
>      at eval (webpack:///multi_(webpack)-dev-server/client?:2:18)
>      at Object.0 (http://localhost:8080/main.js:4015:1)
>      at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8080/main.js:20:30)
>      at http://localhost:8080/main.js:84:18
>      at http://localhost:8080/main.js:87:10

It says it doesn't understand the ReactDOM.render() function.
I even threw in a `<h1>Test</h1>` to see if it was my code but it still bugged out, so I'm sure it's something in my webpack.config.js that isn't right but I just can't figure out what.

### Edit

I gave up on using webpack, I undid my npm eject and went back to just using npm start.

Comment: Why did you comment out "//document.getElementById('root')" in index.js?

Comment: I was testing some stuff out and forgot to remove that before I posted it here. It still doesn’t work without it commented.

Comment: Your Webpack bundle might be loading before the body loads. Usually, you import Webpack by doing `<script defer src="bundle.js">` in the head.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, thank you for the response!

Comment: Do you have this in github? @tan-arin